# JMeter BeanShell PreProcessor modify request

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a JMeter HTTP-Request element which performs a POST call like:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "me"
}
```

I want to load this request body on a `BeanShell PreProcessor` and modify the `name` field, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would recommend re-considering your "Beanshell" approach.

Here is a piece of sample [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code showing how you can amend the request:

```
def payload = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

payload.name = 'some new name'

sampler.getArguments().clear()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

1. Get Request Body:

   String requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
2. Modify request(In my case I modified it as a parsed `JSONObject`)
3. Set the modified request body into the current request:

   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(modifiedRequestObject.toString());